# Python: how to pivot a dataframe that contains lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following

```
df
     A        B
0   'X1'    [3,2,1,5]
1   'X2'    [0,-2,1,2]
2   'X3'    [5,1,1,-6]
```

I would like to get a dataframe like the following one:

```
df
    X1    X2    X3
0   3     0     5
1   2    -2     1
2   1     1     1
3   5     2     6
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert column from `B` to DataFrame with index by `A` column and then transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist(), index=df.A.tolist()).T
print (df)
   'X1'  'X2'  'X3'
0     3     0     5
1     2    -2     1
2     1     1     1
3     5     2    -6
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist(), index=df.A.str.strip("'").tolist()).T
print (df)
   X1  X2  X3
0   3   0   5
1   2  -2   1
2   1   1   1
3   5   2  -6
```